# How to use CSS to create an image overlay effect?

Tags: css

I've designed some hyperlinks with CSS to add a background image (to make it look like a button) using the following code:
`<a class="btnImg" id="btnImgConfig" href="#"></a>`

```
.btnImg {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #e4e4e4;
}

.btnImg:hover {
    opacity: .2;
    background-color: #878787;
}

#btnImgConfig {
    background: url("http://www.icecub.nl/images/config.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to create a darker effect on the image on hover. This is the desired effect:
[image: Desired hover effect]
However, currently the effect is this:
[image: Current hover effect]
I know I could easily do this by replacing the image on hover with a darker version of it. But somehow I feel this shouldn't be the way to do it in this case. Besides what is mentioned above, I've also tried `rgba{..}` on hover. This however had no effect at all.
Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c5Lr1dmn/) of the code above.

Comment: you want the first one, right? A darker background on hover, but the icon itself stays as dark?

Comment: @VladPintea Idealy that would be best. But it's not required. If the icon gets darker, it's not an issue.

Comment: Use a transparent `png` image. Then set the background in CSS for initial and `hover` state

Comment: Do you need the opacity? If the png has a transparent background the `background-color` should come through.

Comment: if the img you're using it's a .png with transparent background you have to change the css property background to another color.

If you're using a .jpg you can't change only the background of the image, because css can't recognize what's the background of an image and what's not.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. Of course I'm using a png. A couple of working solutions are already given. Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could alternatively use a pseudo-element which then overlays. This will give you the effect you require.

```css
.btnImg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  position: relative;
}
.btnImg:hover::after {
  background-color: #878787;
  opacity: 0.4;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#btnImgConfig {
  background: url("http://www.icecub.nl/images/config.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

```html
<a class="btnImg" id="btnImgConfig" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly as well and less work then having the change the images again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put the image's initial opacity to .2, then put it to full opacity on hover.

```css
.btnImg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  opacity: .2;
}
.btnImg:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #878787;
}
#btnImgConfig {
  background: url("http://www.icecub.nl/images/config.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

```html
<a class="btnImg" id="btnImgConfig" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: Turning it around. Can't believe I didn't think of this myself! Thanks a lot. Will give it a try and if it works out, I'll mark as answered.

Comment: Tested it and it's working perfectly! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This does the leave the initial icon being very faint.

Comment: @Stewartside I agree. The solution works, but I'd have to change the images for it. Therefor I think your answer would be better.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Change `opacity: .2;`to `-webkit-filter: brightness(0.5);`

Comment: This made no sense at all. Did you test it yourself? Because your code has no effect at all..

Comment: @icecub This code has no effect at all, if you test it in a non webkit browser. You can make it cross browser, and it will work fine.

Comment: Ah I see. I've tested it with `filter: brightness(0.5);` instead and that works perfectly fine. Thx :)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest approach would be to have the text and tools over a transparent background, and change the background color on hover. No opacity or other such. To make it work without "!important" define the background with background-image, and the color, position, and repeat likewise separately. Or, define the background-color with important (it's ok, it's prescriptive).

Answer (score 2):

What you show in the desired result is not really possible in the current setup..

If you are able to use a png24 file with a transparent background, you can accomplish this more easily, by just changing the background color.

```
#btnImgConfig {
    background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios7-line/512/Tools.png");
    background-size:100%;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.btnImg {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #e4e4e4;
}
#btnImgConfig.btnImg:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/zgurL5t9/ for an example.

Comment: Yes this is what was mentioned to me before. It works just fine. Thanks for your efford.

Answer (score 2):

Your image has a default background color which is causing this issue. try using a transparent PNG image instead along with the background-color property and you should be good to go.
I have updated your Fiddle link slightly for your reference:

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aalok/c5Lr1dmn/3/)

```
#btnImgConfig {
    background: url("http://www.jar2exe.com/sites/default/files/images/pics/config-100.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 #f8f8f8;
}
#btnImgConfig:hover{
    background-color: #878787;
}
```

**Note:** I have used a different image of same size to make it easier for you.

Comment: Although the images isn't usefull to me, your solution does work. Thanks for putting the efford in it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use a **transparent** png here.

You could create a different element within your a href.

```
<a  id="btnImgConfig" href="#"><span class="btnImg"></span></a>
```

Keep the image on the link, but the background-color on the new element.
This way the opacity doesn't change the original background-img

CSS could be something like this.

```
.btnImg {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #e4e4e4;
  position: absolute;
}

.btnImg:hover {
  opacity: .2;
  background-color: #878787;
}

#btnImgConfig {
  background: url("http://www.icecub.nl/images/config.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display: block;
}
```